# Properties of cosets; $aH = bH \iff b^{-1}a \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I've found the concept of cosets to be strange when I've encountered them. I want to make sure that I'm understanding how to work with them.

**Claim:** Given a subgroup $H \leq G$ and $a,b \in G$, we have $aH = bH \iff b^{-1}a \in H$.

**Attempt:**
Assume first that $aH = bH$. This means that as sets
$$
\{g \in G \mid g = ah, h \in H\} = \{g \in G \mid g = bh, h \in H\}.
$$
Therefore if $aH = bH$ then $ah_1 = bh_2$ for some $h_1,h_2 \in H$. This implies that $b^{-1}a = h_2h_1^{-1} \in H$. Conversely assume that $b^{-1}a \in H$. This means that there exists some $h \in H$ such that $b^{-1}a =h$. Then it follows that $a = bh \in bH$ and that $b = ah^{-1} \in aH$. If we pick any arbitrary $h' \in H$ we must have that $ah' = b(hh') \in bH$ but this means that $aH \subseteq bH$. Identically $bh' = a(h^{-1}h') \in aH$ so $bH \subseteq aH$ and we have $aH = bH$.

Is this overkill? Whenever I read problems or questions the manipulations on cosets seem to be much faster. How can I stop thinking of them as sets, or the quotient group $G/H$ as a "set of sets"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are faster because they assume as known what you have correctly proved.

Comment: $aH = bH$ implies $b^{-1}aH = H$. So it must be the case that $b^{-1}a \in H$. Working backwards gives the converse. What you wrote works perfectly fine. I would always think of cosets as sets, because that is what they are. I think a useful trick is $h\in H$ $\leftrightarrow$ $hH = H$, provided $H\leq G$.

Comment: If you use this more often you also will be faster with it, and write this in a short form. But it is certainly useful to write it out once in all detail.

Comment: @KevinS another way to see it: $aH=bH$ implies $a\in bH$.

Comment: Your proof is fine and it is good to know how to do these things from first principles. One useful trick is to note that it is valid to multiply an equation between subsets by a group element: for any $a \in G$ and $X, Y \subseteq G$, $X = Y$ iff $aX = aY$; and also to note that set-multiplication is associative. So you can argue $aH = bH$ iff $(b^{-1}a)H=b^{-1}(aH) = b^{-1}(bH) = (b^{-1}b)H = eH = H$, and $(b^{-1}a)H = H$ iff $b^{-1}a \in H$. The trick makes the reasoning a bit more algebraic in flavour.

Comment: Thank you for all the help getting the concept sorted in my mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, and not necessarily overkill but I'm going to give some feedback on how you wrote it, which might tighten it up.

1. "Therefore if $aH=bH$ then $ah_1=bh_2$ for some $h_1,h_2\in H$." This is not very clear: it looks like a statement involving an existential statement on two elements. What you actually have is that *for every $h_1\in H$* there exists $h_2\in H$ such that $ah_1 = bh_2$, and likewise for every $h_3\in H$ there exists $h_4\in H$ such that $ah_4=bh_3$. You can then deduce your statement, but one usually first *picks* an (arbitrary?) element from $H$ to get the thing started, rather than existentially pick two elements.
2. Note that this allows you to simplify the argument ans make it look more like the converse: *pick* $h_1=e$, and deduce that there exists $h\in H$ such that $a=bh$; then $b^{-1}a=h\in H$ is a simpler calculation. (In particular, notice that the only element of $G$ that you know *for sure* is in $H$ is $e$, so the only instantiation of $h_1$ that you can be sure is valid is $h_1=e$).
3. Once you get that "then there exists $h$ such that $a=bh\in bH$, you can now invoke the fact that two cosets of $H$ are either disjoint or equal. Since $a\in aH\cap bH$, it follows that $aH=bH$ and you are done. No need for double inclusion. But if you want to do double inclusion, once you have that $b^{-1}a\in H$ implies $aH\subseteq bH$, you can then note that because $H$ is a subgroup, then $b^{-1}a\in H$ implies $a^{-1}b=(b^{-1}a)^{-1}\in H$, which implies that $bH\subseteq aH$, giving equality. This exploits the fact that the roles of $a$ and $b$ are symmetric.

An alternative proof that uses the cosets is to note that $gH=H$ if and only if $g\in H$, which is easy to verify (just note that $e\in gH$ if and only if $g^{-1}\in H$ if and only if $g\in H$). So
$$\begin{align*}
aH = bH &\iff b^{-1}(aH) = b^{-1}(bH)\\
&\iff (b^{-1}a)H = (b^{-1}b)H\\
&\iff (b^{-1}a)H = eH\\
&\iff (b^{-1}a)H = H\\
&\iff b^{-1}a\in H.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks very much, cleared up some of the issues in my head.